# Unable to access Dashboard in website running wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, database-deadlocks

When I get logged in to the my website with wordpress it redirects me to the homepage with admin logged in but do not give me access to the dashboard when I tried to go to dashboard, it redirects to the homepage , I check the error log that was like,

```
WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction for query DELETE FROM san_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules' made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('wp_loaded'), call_user_func_array, WP_Rewrite->flush_rules, delete_option
```

How do I solve this error ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There was error with .htaccess file in my site , restoring the .htaccess file helped me . thanks